# jQuery selector question (how to select all input fields on a form EXCEPT buttons and checkbox)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select all input fields on a form (except buttons and checkboxes).

I have got as far as to select all the form input elements on a form with id "myform", but I dont know how to exclude buttons and checkbox items. Does anyone know how to do this?

this is what I have so far:

```
$("#myform :input")
```

How do I "filter out" buttons and checkboxes on the form?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
$("#myform :input:not(:checkbox):not(:button)");
```

Comment: I *LOVE* jQuery - its so intuitive!

Comment: Whether [type="submit"] isn't part of the question or [type="image"] should be added?

Comment: What about: $("#myform input:not(:radio)") ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) combined to [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [:button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selectors:

```
$("#myform :input:not(:button):not(:checkbox)");
```

and test it with success with the [example](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) provided in the documentation of :input

EDIT: `:input` also selects `textarea`, `select`, `button` and `input[type="hidden"]` according to [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) (and a useful example)

Comment: You just beat me to it... and a little cleaner too