# jQuery :not selector

Tags: jquery

I am interesting which method is faster: `:not` selector or `not()` method.
For example in such query:

```
$(this).find(':input').not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').each(function() { ... });
```

Thank you

Comment: Wild guess is that they use the same mechanism, so that makes `:not` slightly faster due to not having to call a whole new function.

Comment: I agree with Kolink. I guess you'd see the difference if you use the profiling tools of Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

:not is on average is about twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Try this please:

Good read: [jQuery selector question (how to select all input fields on a form EXCEPT buttons and checkbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129151/jquery-selector-question-how-to-select-all-input-fields-on-a-form-except-button)

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

This should help your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(this).find(':input:not(:button):not(:submit):not(:reset)').each(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

As kolink said `:not` is faster because you're not adding a function call, you can compare speeds in [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

for example: [in this test](http://jsperf.com/not-vs-not2131/2)