# jQuery how to select all input fields APART from submit button

Tags: jquery

I am currently selecting all the input fields of a form using jQuery in the following way:

```
$('#new_user_form *').filter(':input').each(function(key, value) {
```

This works fine although it selects the submit input as well which I don't want it to do. 
Is there a simple way of making it ignore the submit button?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector question (how to select all input fields on a form EXCEPT buttons and checkbox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129151/jquery-selector-question-how-to-select-all-input-fields-on-a-form-except-button)

Comment: I assume you used `.filter` because of the performance warning in the docs. Selecting *all* descendants and then filtering is the wrong approach though. Just use the multiple selector if you want to get all form elements: `$('#new_user_form *').find('input:not([type="submit"]), button, textarea, select')`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `:not()`:

```
$('#new_user_form input:not([type="submit"])')
```

Also, be careful with `:input` and other non-standard selectors. They don't have the same speed benefit as native selectors on browsers that implement `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: or it might be easier to read: `$('#new_user_form input').not('[type="submit"]')`

Comment: Well blow me down, the demo certainly supports your assertion. I wonder if the extra load is the creation of a further jQuery object? I think I would still use `.not()` for readability, but thank you for putting me right.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: When you use `.not()`, jQuery is using JavaScript to filter those elements. When you use a single (valid) selector, newer browsers use hardware acceleration and other fancy stuff not available to JS to find them.

Comment: @Blender, "fancy stuff not available to JS" - can you provide a reference please?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Take a look at [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and the additional notes on the jQuery [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector page. Sorry, "not available to JS" is a bad way of putting it.

Comment: That's OK, I understand "fancy stuff not used by JS in all circumstances". Thanks for the link.

Comment: I knew `.not` would be slower when I suggested it (thanks @Blender for proving), but IMO that's a micro-optimisation (ie, it's better just to go with the more readable option).

Comment: @NathanMacInnes: Yep. It really depends on what you consider readable.

Comment: @Blender, yes. I think `.not` is more readable, but I can understand if someone prefers something else. It'd be easy to break it down to excessive levels too!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var inputs = $('#new_user_form input').not(':input[type=submit]');

$(inputs).each(function() {
    // your code...
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sawrW/1/)

**UPDATE** *(based on @Blender inputs)*

```
var inputs = $('#new_user_form input').not('[type=submit]');

$(inputs).each(function() {
    // your code...
});​
```

[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/sawrW/2/)

Comment: `inputs` is already a jQuery object, so there's no need to re-wrap it in the jQuery function again.

Comment: Yes, i just tested it. Its working without the input again. Thanks for pointing out that :)